# Building an array out of values from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a follow up from a question of mine that was just answered [concerning parsing numbers in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580655/parsing-numbers-in-a-javascript-array).

I have an array, `data[]`, with numbers that I'd like to use in a calculation and then put the resulting values into another array.

So say `data[0] = 100`.  I'd like to find a percentage using the calculatin, `(data[0]/dataSum*100).toFixed(2)` where `dataSum` is the sum of all the numbers in `data[]`.

I've tried:

```
dataPercentage = [];

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = parseFloat(data[i]);
    dataSum += data[i];

    // looping through data[i] and setting it equal to dataPercentage.
    dataPercentage[] = (data[i]/dataSum*100).toFixed(2);

    // thought maybe I was overriding dataPercentage everytime I looped? 
    dataPercentage[] += (data[i]/dataSum*100).toFixed(2); 
}
```

I also tried just setting `dataPercentage = [(data/dataSum*100).toFixed(2)]`, but I think this creates a nested array, which I don't think is what I need.

Comment: should `dataPercentage[]` be `dataPercentage[i]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to calculate the sum of all values in `data` **before** you calculate the percentage. In your code you always use the sum **up to the `i`th item** of the `data` array.

```
var dataSum = 0.0;
var dataPercentage = [];

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = parseFloat(data[i]);
    dataSum += data[i];
}

for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    dataPercentage[i] = (data[i]/dataSum*100).toFixed(2); 
}
```

I don't know what you try to achieve with your second `dataPercentage[]` line.

Comment: @George - it's good etiquette to up-vote to an answer that helps you.  At least, I think so.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
dataPercentage.push((data[i]/dataSum*100).toFixed(2))
```